# sql performance when filtering ipv4 ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a database(InnoDB) with Ipv4 ranges represented as 32bit int, both are unsigned int and represent a certain IP range (start-ip to end-ip) with data in other columns. I have indexed both columns individually (BTree index type).

```
id|start-ip|end-ip
 4|16777216|16777471
 5|16777472|16778239
 6|16778240|16779263
 7|16779264|16781311
 8|16781312|16785407
 9|16785408|16793599
10|16793600|16809983
11|16809984|16810018
12|16810019|16810019
```

When selecting a certain IP I can easily find one as it fits within a single row. But when I need to find a range of ips that need to fit within multiple rows the only way I figured was

```
select * from `ips` where 
(`start-ip` <= min and `end-ip` >= min) 
or 
(`start-ip` >= min and `end-ip` <= max) 
or 
(`start-ip` <= max and `end-ip` >= max)
```

for example, trying to select from a range of 16777300(min) - 16779200(max) the output would be

```
 4|16777216|16777471
 5|16777472|16778239
 6|16778240|16779263
```

Essentially the start-ip must be smaller or equal to the 'min' while the end-ip must be larger or equal to the 'max'. This can be across multiple rows.

Currently, I have roughly 10 mil rows with ip ranges for the full spectrum of ipv4 and this selects all the rows that fit within the range, however, performance-wise it takes a few seconds to extract the data. How can I improve performance?

Comment: I would suggest to check query plan first to understand how query is executed. Have you tried to create index on both fields? This could improve performance as DBMS does not need to read 2 indexes and combine results.

Comment: @AntonProkofiev Do you mean an index a combination of both fields?

Comment: @ hyperalghorithm  yes.  something like create index my_index on table XXX (start_ip,end_ip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this logic:

```
select *
from `ips`
where min <= `end-ip` and
      max >= `start-ip`
```

That is, one range start before the other ends . . . and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you,
Originally I tried it like that however it wasn't showing me the proper output. I may have written something wrong... much better :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL/MariaDB does not know that your ranges might be overlapping or not.  Hence performance sucks for any obvious formulation, including Gordon's

Here is an approach that is performant:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

Comment: Hmm this would include that there is an 'owner' to the ip range which would drastically reduce the number of ip's i'm searching for.
in my case i don't have a specific owner but other information about the ip's and when searching for a range it could any kind of range (from maybe 1-2 ranges to hundreeds)